# Inserting tuple's elements to database

Tags: python, sqlite, lastinsertid

I have a tuple that i wanna store its elements, I'm trying to insert it as following and it gives the following error, what am i doing wrong ? records_to_be_inserted is the tuple that has 8 elements.

```
with self.connection:
        cur = self.connection.cursor()
        cur.executemany("INSERT INTO rehberim(names, phone, mobile, email, \
                        photo, address, note, date) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", self.records_to_be_inserTed)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tayfun/workspace/personal_guide/modules/mainwindow.py", line 57, in save_records
    photo, address, note, date) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", self.records_to_be_inserTed)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 8, and there are 0 supplied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query must have all the data ready to be inserted.
You are calling a function in the query, which i guess you want that provides the data but that wont work.
You need to pass all the data in variables or locate them in the tuple index (like: tuple_name[1], tuple_name[4], etc.)

Example:

```
myTuple = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO rehberim(names, phone, mobile, email, \
                    photo, address, note, date) VALUES({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}" .format (myTuple[1], myTuple[2], myTuple[3], myTuple[4], myTuple[5], myTuple[6], myTuple[7])
```

Comment: I set it as tuple cuz when i do as you said, it gives the following error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tayfun/workspace/personal_guide/modules/mainwindow.py", line 58, in save_records
    self.mob_num, self.email, self.photo, self.address, self.note, self.celeb)
TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (9 given)

Comment: @dex19dt -> remember that the list you use is zero based so you should use myTuple[0], etc not start with 1. At the same time just unpack the list if the order is correct. That would save some space: `.format(*myTuple)`

Comment: I think he just wanted to show me the way, thanks but it also gives error on mine, format() asks for exactly 2 arguments and 1 is given.

Comment: Yeah - There is a lot of possibilities when using the format (i assume that is what you are using now) e.g., you can use dictionaries to format in the correct order

Comment: Don't format SQL statements (unless you can't do it any other way, such as if you're substituting in the table name) because that makes it horribly easy to hit SQL injection problems.

Comment: you really need to use executemany? It seems to be simple just run the execute if you dont have more columns in the table.

Comment: Yeah I did not need to use it :-) I've now solved what I have asked, thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the `executemany` is for inserting multiple rows, e.g.,

```
import sqlite3

""" the table structure is:
create table tab
    a char(1),
    b char(2),
    c char(3)
)
"""

conn = sqlite3.connect('C:\\test.db')
stmt = "insert into tab (a, b, c) values (?, ?, ?)"

cur = conn.cursor()
## many rows
vals = [('1','2','3'), ('2','3','4'), ('3','4','5')]

cur.executemany(stmt, vals)
cur.close()
```

This will result in three rows in the database. If it is because you have multiple values in one query, you need to format it!

**Edit**: Added formatting with dictionaries

By using the following approach you do not need to consider the order of the values in the `format` call because the key in the dictionary is mapping the value into the `{key_word}` placeholder.

```
values = {'a' : 'value_a',
          'b' : 'value_b'}

stmt = "insert into tab (col_a, col_b) values ({a}, {b})".format(**values)
```

Comment: Don't format SQL statements (unless you can't do it any other way, such as if you're substituting in the table name) because that makes it horribly easy to hit SQL injection problems.

Comment: what i wanna do is not to insert multiple rows at once, say, i have just 5 string objects and 6 fields on db, 1 is for auto id and 5 is for strings.