# Python and Sqlite3 inserting elements error

Tags: python, sqlite, syntax-error, qt-designer

I am trying to write data archive application. I have a GUI (PyQT Designer) that show a questions form to user. There are 13 questions and answers are yes or no. And there are 13 explanation for them. I create a table in database, it has 29 column. First column is date and it is primary key. First I tried to TEXT format to date and explanations. I gave to VARCHAR(5) yes and no's. But it didn't work with same error with this:

[Here is the first error I gave,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051439/inserting-tuples-elements-to-database)

I applied that solution to my code like this:

```
isaretci.execute('INSERT INTO onceKontrol (tarih, cvp1, aciklama1, cvp2, \
                                aciklama2, cvp3, aciklama3, cvp4, \
                                aciklama4, cvp5, aciklama5, cvp6, \
                                aciklama6, cvp7, aciklama7, cvp8, \
                                aciklama8, cvp9, aciklama9, cvp10, \
                                aciklama10, cvp11, aciklama11, cvp12, \
                                aciklama12, cvp13, aciklama13) VALUES \
                                ({0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10},\
                                {11},{12},{13},{14},{15},{16},{17},{18},{19},\
                                {20},{21},{22},{23},{24},{25},{26}'\
                                .format (self.once[0], self.once[1], self.once[2], \
                                self.once[3], self.once[4], self.once[5], \
                                self.once[6], self.once[7], self.once[8], \
                                self.once[9], self.once[10], self.once[11], \
                                self.once[12], self.once[13], self.once[14], \
                                self.once[15], self.once[16], self.once[17], \
                                self.once[18], self.once[19], self.once[20], \
                                self.once[21], self.once[22], self.once[23], \
                                self.once[24], self.once[25], self.once[26]) )
```

tarih mean date, `cvp[i]` mean answer, `aciklama[i]` mean explanation. Now it is giving me this error:

```
self.once[24], self.once[25], self.once[26],) )
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing parenthesie

The Insert statement needs to be like `INSERT INTO table (header,...) VALUES (val,...)`

```
 (   {0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10},\
  {11},{12},{13},{14},{15},{16},{17},{18},{19},\
  {20},{21},{22},{23},{24},{25},{26}   )' #added here
```

You should also be using the safe approach

```
.execute("INSERT ... VALUES (%s)" % ("?"*len(self.once)),self.ounce)
```

Comment: I did all of your advices. Error changed but not gone.
    (%s)' % ("?"*len(self.once)), self.once)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error

Comment: I solved this problem. I wrote sql syntax in a string variable. It is really important put " , " and " ' " in syntax. My mistake was here. Thank you.